# Docker for Windows does not work with Volumes

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2015, docker-compose, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I'm trying to create a project with ASP.NET Core, **Docker Desktop for Windows** and **Visual Studio Docker Tools**.

So I've create a ASP.NET Core Empty Project and added Docker Support via context menu.

My docker-compose.debug.yml looks like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  aspnetcore_rtm_windows_docker_sample:
image: username/aspnetcore_rtm_windows_docker_sample:Debug
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile.debug
environment:
  - REMOTE_DEBUGGING=${REMOTE_DEBUGGING}
ports:
  - "80:80"
volumes:
  - .:/app
```

When I start, nothing happens. Browser returns host not found and debug of Visual Studio is stopping.

But I already have investigated the problem, if I remove the volume entry, it works fine. Browser returns `Hello world` and I can debug the ASP.NET Core sample inside the docker container.

Can somebody tell me why?

Docker Shared Drive is active (drive `C:\`). My project is located unter `C:\` and also tried to use a different drive.
Anybody has an idea, why the volume entry is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a clean install of my Windows, everything works now.
After installing Kaspersky: the same effect.

So dont use Kaspersky if u wanna develop in this scenario at this moment.
It does not help do deactivate the protection. After uninstallation it works again.

I already have created a ticket at Kaspersky.